# Rails routing to another directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncontroller

Is there a way to direct a route to use a view that isn't in the expected folder?

Here's my problem... I'm creating a new view for my `Reports`, however I'm getting `Missing template v1/reports/index` error.

**routes.rb**

```
api_version(module: "V1", path: { value: "v1" }) do
  resources :reports, only: [:create, :index]
end
```

**views/reports/index.html.erb**

```
<h3>Just some test content</h3>
```

**controllers/v1/reports_controller.rb**

```
class V1::ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @company = current_user.company

   reports = if @company
    @company.reports.order("created_at DESC")
   else
    []
   end
  end
end
```

**_navigation.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "Reports", v1_reports_path, role: "menuItem" %>
```

I used `apipie` to create some API for my application which has many of my controllers under a 'v1' directory within my app which is now causing some issues as I expand my app (I think).  I don't want to have to redo the structure so hopefully there is a way to direct the route to use the view under `views/reports/` instead of `v1/reports/` which is what it is looking for which doesn't exist.

...or am I stuck with also having to create a `views/v1/reports/index.html.erb' file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be able to just tell your controller what path to render

```
class V1::ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @company = current_user.company

   reports = if @company
    @company.reports.order("created_at DESC")
   else
    []
   end
  end
  render '/path/to/views/reports/index.html.erb'
end
```

see section 2.2.3 and 2.2.5 of the docs for the [render method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render)

although really, you should be using the directory rails wants you to. mainly because if there is a v2 controller made down the road, where would you put its views?